# jQuery wont turn this is into JSON

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

so my code I want to turn into JSON is the following

```
var locationData = [];
locationData['lat'] = position.coords.latitude;
locationData['long'] = position.coords.longitude;
locationData['address']['road'] = data['address']['road'];
locationData['address']['suburb'] = data['address']['suburb'];
locationData['address']['city'] = data['address']['city'];
locationData['address']['county'] = data['address']['county'];
locationData['address']['state'] = data['address']['state'];
locationData['address']['postcode'] = data['address']['postcode'];
locationData['address']['country'] = data['address']['country'];
locationData['address']['country_code'] = data['address']['country_code'];
```

But when I run it, It does not alert me that it has been successful

Comment: Alert? There's no alert in your code. Try `console.log`ing the JSON and check if it's well-formed.

Comment: What context are you using this array in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your initial declaration is wrong:

```
var locationData = [];
```

That creates an array, which will not work as you would expect; you want an object instead. You also need to initialize any complex data structure inside, such as `address`:

```
var locationData = {
    address: {}
}
```

---

**Sidenote**

An array is also an object in JavaScript, but it behaves in a special way when using numeric properties. In your case you're not using numeric properties at all, which is why a regular object suits your needs better.

Comment: In essence, javascript objects *are* associative arrays, you just have to declare them as objects, not arrays.

Comment: Oh yes, in JS basically everything is an object (even indexed arrays).

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Right, I've added a side note to my answer :)

Comment: Nicely explained, sometimes I wish I've had teachers which would know how to explain 1/10 in-depth as SO answerers. `=]`

Answer (score 0):

Just as you declare the locationData as an array, you need to declare locationData['address'] as an array too. (`locationData['address']=[]` on your third or fourth line).